# Is it possible to turn off Hot Deployment in TomCat?

Tags: tomcat7

Is it possible to turn off  Hot Deployment in tomcat? Has anyone done this before? Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Set autoDeploy="false" on the Host element in server.xml